# quebra de linha de um edittext automaticamente no android

Tags: android, edittext

Ola!
no meu aplicativo o cliente pode fazer um comentario com até 300 caracteres, só que fica ruim fazer longos textos com o edittext somente em um linha
entao como quebrar a linha automaticamente? um exemplo é quando vamos fazer comentarios no facebook, o texto vai quebrando a linha e descendo em vez de sumir como é de costume no edittext,

um exemplo no meu edittext:
Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica

gostaria que ficasse assim:
Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação
 de texto da indústria tipográfica
Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação
 de texto da indústria tipográfica
Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação 
de texto da indústria tipográfica

Comment: Não tenho um código pronto para te mostrar, mas pesquisa sobre altura miníma e máxima do edittext e não esquece de deixar o atributo "singleLine" como falso. Não ajudei muito, mas acho que é um caminho

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda Guilherme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar os atributos `maxLines` e/ou `inputType`, desse jeito:

```
  <EditText
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:maxLines="5"
       android:inputType="textMultiLine"
       android:textSize="16sp" />
```

No seu caso, acredito que apenas usando o `inputType="textMultiLine"` já vai resolver, e o texto irá quebrar conforme inserção.

Comment: resolveu o problema, obrigado!